# How to execute mathematical expression stored in a varchar variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a variable in my database function:

```
@LocalVariable = '2*3*100'
```

I want to get the result by executing the expression in another variable. May any one advise on how to execute the expression?  Also, I want to do it in a database function (not in a stored procedure).  The result I expect is 600.

Comment: @Aaron... your blood pressure. :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the reply. I am not sure whom to accept. So I am choosing the one having more rank.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `sp_executesql`:

```
declare @expression nvarchar(max)
set @expression = '2*3*100'

declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'select @result = ' + @expression

declare @result int
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@result int output', @result = @result out

select @result
```

[Example at SE Data.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/112490/)

Comment: Thanks for reply but sp_executesql can't be used in database function

Comment: Egads. "I want to walk to New York." "But sir, you're in Baghdad." "I don't care; I want to walk."

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: This is more like walking from Manhattan to Queens, except that there's one of those mysterious SQL Server restrictions in place.  Perhaps this could be done using CLR integration.

Comment: Ok, have fun walking him through that project. :-) Anyway there's a reason dynamic SQL is not allowed in a function (no mystery): the same reason you can't have an UPDATE or DELETE in a function - you can't produce side effects, and there's no way to prevent the dynamic SQL from having side effects.

Comment: @Aaron: if you want you can walk to Newyork too :). Look at the solution.

Answer (score 8):

```
DECLARE @LocalVariable VARCHAR(32);
SET @LocalVariable = '2*3*100';
EXEC('SELECT ' + @LocalVariable);
```

To get it into a variable:

```
DECLARE @LocalVariable VARCHAR(32);
SET @LocalVariable = '2*3*100';

DECLARE @out INT, @sql NVARCHAR(4000);
SET @sql = N'SELECT @out = ' + @LocalVariable;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@out INT OUTPUT', @out OUTPUT;

PRINT @out;
```

However you can't do this in a function, because you can't use EXEC, sp_executesql etc. in a function, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for reply; but sp_executesql can't be used in database function

Comment: Yes, I know, and that was kind of my point: you *CAN'T* do what you're trying to do in a function. You can't pass a string into a function and have it evaluate that as an expression. It's not going to work, so you're going to need to loosen your restriction that this must be done in a function.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying see is any solution avaialble for this problem.

Comment: Yes, there are plenty of solutions, they just don't involve UDFs because dynamic SQL is required, and dynamic SQL is *not allowed* in UDFs.

Comment: I was about to do it with CRL integration, but i just wanted to confirm it is not possible through direct database function.

Comment: No, you CANNOT do it with a UDF. Can I ask why this absolutely needs to be in a function?

Answer (score 4):

I got a better solution, I though of sharing with you all

```
DECLARE @x xml
DECLARE @v FLOAT
SET @x = ''
SET @v = @x.value('(1 + 4) div 3', 'FLOAT')
SELECT @v
```

This will work in function too.

Comment: Great. Have you validated that this will work for the full range of mathematical expressions you expect to support? And at what point will you change all of your `/` operators to `div`?

Comment: Yes, at least it works for my requirement, only change i have to make in the expression is before i execute, I have to replace all the'/' with div. Thanks

Comment: http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/dan/archive/2006/07/27/32597.aspx

Comment: When i trying to pass nvarchar string to your query...it doesn't work...it gives conversion error...

i have a dynamic values not fixed like this '(1 + 4) div 3'...

DECLARE @x xml
DECLARE @v decimal(20,4)
SET @x = ''
DECLARE @calculatedDataString nvarchar(1000) = '(14566.2000)-(39879.3600)'
SET @v= @x.value('sql:variable("@calculatedDataString")', 'decimal(20,4)')
SELECT @v


it will give me error

Comment: its giving error `The argument 1 of the XML data type method "value" must be a string literal.` when i pass variable as first parameter

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @LocalVariable NVARCHAR(100)
SET @LocalVariable = '2*3*100'
EXEC ('SELECT ' + @LocalVariable)
```

Comment: This doesn't store the result in a variable though

Comment: EXEC - can't be used in database function.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @KBBWrite you won't be able to do any dynamic SQL inside a function, so your solution is not going to be "how can I evaluate this expression in a function" but rather "how can I get this result without using a function."